# nsstring for HH:SS into nsdate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSString *dateString = @"06:30 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM:SS a"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

When i log the "dateFromString" it give me nil.

expected result is :

```
 19-10-2016 06:30
```

Please help

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31217006/775896 You might require to replicated the code from Swift to Objective-C.

Comment: The code you're really looking to do can be found [in this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707648/constructing-an-nsdate-from-todays-date-and-a-string-with-the-time).

Comment: I have One answer but It will give output like this 2000-01-01 06:30:00 +0000 because You dont have define date, It will taken as default. If you want answer then I will post it

Comment: You are setting the minute parameter wrongly. SO instead of "MM" it should be "mm". Capital "MM" for month and "mm" for minute. You are getting nil, as the format of string date does not match with the format you have mentioned.

Comment: @ios developer check my answer. As per you dont give date in your string, It will take default date

Comment: now that I think about this more, the question is also bad because OP's expected result is "`19-10-2016 06:30`" (which is a string) while NSDate (when printed out via NSLog) will always have a description of "`2016-10-19 06:30:00 +0000`".  You need to convert your input date string into a NSDate and then back into a string (with your expected result) via another date formatter.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann As per your comment, My answer is correct as per some scenario so please remove donwvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try this, might be solve ur problem

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *urDateComponents = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:today];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

NSString *dateString = @"06:30 AM";
NSDate *urTime = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSDateComponents *urTimeComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute ) fromDate:urTime];

urDateComponents.hour = urTimeComponents.hour;
urDateComponents.minute = urTimeComponents.minute;

NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:urDateComponents];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString *dateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Output:

> Printing description of dateStr: 19-10-2016 06:30 AM

Happy coding...

Comment: You're welcome, it has been my pleasure to help you out!